# Access MinIO API on Port 80

Tags: minio

My MinIO API is listening on IP of the server and port 9000. It works fine.

However, if I try to change the port to 80 and restart the service, it fails to start:

```
● minio.service - MinIO
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/minio.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-10-25 12:37:04 CEST; 1s ago
       Docs: https://docs.min.io
    Process: 27026 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ -z "${MINIO_VOLUMES}" ]; then echo "Variable MINIO_VOLUMES not set in>
    Process: 27027 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/minio server $MINIO_OPTS $MINIO_VOLUMES (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 27027 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 25 12:37:03 hel-sto-01 systemd[1]: minio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 25 12:37:03 hel-sto-01 systemd[1]: minio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 25 12:37:04 hel-sto-01 systemd[1]: minio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 25 12:37:04 hel-sto-01 systemd[1]: Stopped MinIO.
Oct 25 12:37:04 hel-sto-01 systemd[1]: minio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 25 12:37:04 hel-sto-01 systemd[1]: minio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 25 12:37:04 hel-sto-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start MinIO.
```

It's a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 server and I have nothing listening on port 80.

As soon as I revert back to port 9000, MinIO works normally.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is an unprivileged user set in the `minio.service` unit file?

The [default minio.service](https://github.com/minio/minio-service/blob/master/linux-systemd/minio.service) uses an unprivileged user.

> Note: If you want to bind to a port < 1024 with the service running as a regular user, you will need to add bind capability via the AmbientCapabilities directive in the minio.service file:

```
[Service]
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/
```

[minio linux-systemd](https://github.com/minio/minio-service/tree/master/linux-systemd)